# Centering Widgets in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to build a centered three section footer.

joshuasommer.net

Here is what I have...

```
.widget-area {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.widget-title {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.widget {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
```

I've already built the sections. I just need to center them on the page.

Answer (score 0):

In your footer add two `<aside>` section to one another div with class `widget-child` and give css to this class

```
<div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
    <div class="widget-child">
        <aside id="nav_menu-3" class="widget widget_nav_menu"></aside>
        <aside id="nav_menu-4" class="widget widget_nav_menu"></aside>
    </div>
</div>

.widget-child {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```